# Do I still Need To use cookies and session if i use JWT Django rest_framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm devlopping an app and I want to use jwt to authenticate uses.
so, Do I Need To use cookies and session_id and can i delete them from settings.py?

for ex:
'django.contrib.sessions',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are speaking **only** about authentication, then yes, you can.

But keep in mind, that usually applications, that are developed using django+drf, have an admin page.